# Create only content of accordion in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm trying to create the content part of an accordion in a for loop, with the title printed beforehand. This is what I tried:

```
$("#right").append(
        "Team Leaders"
        + "<h4>Goals</h4>"
        + "<div><p>"
    );
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#right").append(
            topGoals[i].name
            + ": "
            + topGoals[i].goals
            + "<br>"
        );
    }
    $("#right").append("</p></div>");
    $("#right").accordion();
```

However, that didn't work. The "Goals" part did appear as the accordion header, but the content inside of it was empty, and the content generated from the for loop appeared underneath the accordion.

I've created accordions in for loops before and had no trouble, but I've never tried to make the title outside of the loop. Am i doing something wrong here?

Edit:

The topGoals array in screen.js:

```
var topGoals = getTopFiveGoals(myTeam);
```

The function is in functions.js:

```
function getTopFiveGoals(team) {
var tempTeam = team.players.slice();
tempTeam.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.goals-a.goals;
});
tempTeam.splice(5, 15);
return tempTeam;
}
```

Comment: You should provide us the `topGoals` array

Comment: The array isn't fixed - it's generated from a function, using a team as an input, which also has randomly generated players in it. So, the topGoals array is different every time, but it does have the correct information inside of it.

Comment: Show an example of it then!

Comment: Just remember in jQuery that you can't append unclosed HTML elements—they will be closed, if necessary—leading to creation of a lot of empty elements. It's different from using string concatenation, where you can combine or separate open and close tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the DOM tree many times, instead create a dom element in memory and append all child elements. At the end append it to the live DOM tree. In your code, the tags are not closed properly so it won't be generated properly.
jQuery will automatically close the tags such as `<div><p>` which are not closed properly.

```
$("#right").append(
        "Team Leaders"
        + "<h4>Goals</h4>"
    );
    var $div = $("<div></div>");
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $div.append("<p>"+
            topGoals[i].name
            + ": "
            + topGoals[i].goals
            + "</p><br>"
        );
    }
    $("#right").append($div);
    $("#right").accordion();
```

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect! I hadn't even thought about doing it that way before.